# Check number of character from command line

Tags: java, command-line

I am trying to solve this question: Write a program that passes a string to the command line and displays the number of uppercase letters in the string.

The test is ProgrammingIsFun, so the count would be three.

Here is what I have so far

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    int count = 0;


    for(int i = 0; i < args.length;i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j >= i; j++)
        if(Character.isUpperCase(args[i].charAt(j)))
            count++;
    }
    System.out.print("The number of upper cases are: " + count);
}
```

when this runs it does count the correct number of uppercases but it runtimes when it reaches the end of the characters(16). I can't figure out how to stop the loop right after the last character. I know the count is correct because I can see it in the debug. I can see something called arg0 in the variables. That has the correct number of characters but I can't use it.

I am still learning and I can't use objects or anything like that for now.
Any help would be appreciated. or if you could point me somewhere I could read. I tried the docs but it was a lot and I got overwhelmed fairly quickly.

Comment: You want `for(int j = 0; j < args[i].length(); j++)`. `args[i]` will get you `String` object, and `length()` will get you the length of the `String`, which will let you iterate over each character

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in the inner loop:

`for(int j = 0; j >= i; j++)`

Note that the outer loop is run for each of the command line argument and the inner loop is run for each character of an argument given by i.

So change it to

`for(int j = 0; j < args[i].length(); j++)`

Answer (score 0):

`for(int j = 0; j < args[i].length(); j++)`?

This will sum all uppercases for all strings passed as arguments.
Your code could be simpler if you only expect one string.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code easier to read (and write) you should use `foreach` loops, one for each string in the `args` array, and one for each character in the array that we get by doing `foo.toCharArray()`.
The syntax of a `foreach` loop is as follows:

```java
for (type var : iterable) {
    // Code here
}
```

Where `iterable` is something with the `Iterable` interface (usually an array or ArrayList).

We can switch out these in your code and make it a lot easier to read:

```java
String[] args = {"ProgrammingIsFun!", "When It Works..."};

int count = 0;
for (String e : args) {
    for (char f : e.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(f)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
System.out.print("The number of upper cases are: " + count);
```

Comment: Thanks for that forreach tip. i'll make sure to use it more I don't know if I can use .toCharArray(). My teacher never brought that up but I will keep it in mind as I progress.